How can I make sure that VSCode always runs my code fully not just partially?
enter image description here
when i try to process and run my code, after enter your age, it does not process it further. i don't know why is it happening.
PS: I am very much a newbie at programming right now trying to grasp the basics of it
i want the code to run further and not just stop at where it has stopped as shown in the snip

Post text not picutres of code.  Your IDE is not relevant so leave it out of the title, or tag with your IDE if it is relevant.  Your problem is the trailing " \n" on scanf so remove that from the format string.

The canonical duplicate for this problem is What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?  However, the question has been closed as a typo, which I don't regard as the best option.

See Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

The executed code does match the shown code in editor. Your code prints : while your output shows =. You need to save your code before you can compile it.

VSCode does not run your code.  It is not responsible for its "completeness".  It is independent compiled executable, it runs itself - no interpreter or VM.

Remove the /n from your scanf. It Should work

You might want to enhance your answer. There is no '/n' and it does not explain why the OP should do what you suggest.
